# <q> versus <p> with quotation marks

Tags: html, css

The `<q>` element for short quotes adds quotation marks to the text:

```
<p><q>This is a quote.</q></p>
```

Can you tell me how this is advantageous to simply using quote characters (i.e. " ") directly within a paragraph?

```
<p>"This is a quote."</p>
```

One could style it specially, but it seems like one could use a `<span>` element for that too, so what's the main advantage(s) of the `<q>` element?

Comment: Do you know definition of the word ["Semantics"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML)?

Comment: @Joseph, a comment describing semantics for a reason to use it is way more advantageous to the person asking than a smart-ass comment.

Comment: @Scott - You're right, and I stand corrected. Regarding w3schools: even though in this particular case "it clearly shows the difference", we still should not get people used to visiting that site, since it has [a lot of wrong information](http://w3fools.com/) (not even mentioning their [shady SEO practices](http://www.impressivewebs.com/web-development-search-results-manipulated/)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main advantage of using the `q` element is the potential semantic meaning it adds to the content, it *describes* the content as being a quote. It also allows browsers with the locale information to style the quotation marks appropriately for that region, `"` for most English-speaking regions, `«` and  `»` for Spain and France, and so on, appropriate for the user's language settings. In theory, at least.

Comment: Unfortunately, for bizarre reasons many CSS resets undo this altogether. Even [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) kills the quotes by default, just because older versions of IE aren't aware of the `<q>` element. A major letdown if you ask me.

Comment: Yep; I try to remember to undo that aspect of CSS-resets. This is not always successful, to my embarrassment.

Comment: Thanks - do you know which older version of IE this is a problem with?  If it's IE 6 or sooner later then not an issue (for me), would prefer to use the q, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is in the semantic markup. Your browser may show them similarly, but other tools (such as a screen reader) may interpret and present them much more differently.

Answer (score 2):

The reason to use it is mainly semantic. The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-q-element.html) makes it clear that the `<q>` element has a very specific semantic meaning (emphasis added):

> The q element represents some phrasing content **quoted from another
>   source**...
>   Content inside a q element must be quoted from another source...
>
> The q element must not be used in place of quotation marks that do not represent quotes; for example, it is inappropriate to use the q element for marking up sarcastic statements.

If you use a `<p>` element, you do not have the same semantic meaning. However, the spec also points out that this is acceptable:

> The use of q elements to mark up quotations is entirely optional;
>   using explicit quotation punctuation without q elements is just as
>   correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is not advantageous. On the contrary, it means that the presence and type of quotation marks will depend on the browser; the `q` element has a sad history.

I don’t think anyone has presented any actual benefits of using “semantic” markup instead of quotation marks, which are just punctuation marks comparable to periods and commas. There has been a lot of talk about things that programs could do, upon encountering `q`, and little if any efforts in really making them do something with it (apart from adding quotation marks in rendering).

Using real quotation marks instead, you can control the exact symbols used, such as “American” vs. ‘British’ vs. « French » vs. ”Finnish” vs. »different Finnish» according to content language. There is normally no reason to let this depend on browser handling of markup like `q` or on CSS, any more than you should use markup and CSS to terminate your sentences instead of just using full stop (“.”).

However, in the rare case where you wish to make the device for indicating quotations depend on styling (so that it can be changed in a centralized manner just by changing a style sheet), you can use the `span` element, e.g.

```
<span class=q><span class=qm>“</span>This is a quote.<span class=qm>”</span></span>
```

Then you could change the rendering to italic without quotation marks by setting

```
.q .qm { display: none; }
.q { font-style: italic; }
```

Using `span`, which has no default rendering features, you avoid the problems of inconsistent implementations of `q`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that any computer program parsing the page would know that it represents a quote.  It's the same reason you use <li> instead of just dashes and <br>.